# How to back-calculate a Url / Uri from two partial Uris and an assumption

Tags: c#

I have a relative path stored in a database field. It looks like this:

```
/images/2012-6/file.jpg
```

I can access the absolute Url via:

```
http://www.blah.com/images/2012-6/file.jpg
```

The thumbnail relative path isn't stored in the database table. However I know that it can be found on:

```
http://www.blah.com/images/thumbnails/2012-6/file.jpg
```

Given I know `http://www.blah.com/` and `/images/2012-6/file.jpg`, what is the best algorithm to determine:

```
http://www.blah.com/images/thumbnails/2012-6/file.jpg
```

Note: The naming scheme could be multiple folders deep on both the relative path and the thumbnail folder root path. i.e. `/images/whatever/something/thumbnails/"`.

The one and only assumption that you can make is that both will start with the same first segment (folder). i.e. `/images/`.

This is in a console app (no `System.Web` if I can help it). This is [the best I have come up](http://dotnetfiddle.net/7HHE0s) with so far:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var test = GetThumbnail("http://www.blah.com/", "/images/folder/subfolder/test/again/filename.jpg", "/images/extra/thumbnails/");
    Console.WriteLine(test);
}

private static string GetThumbnail(string baseUriString, string relativePath, string thumbsPath)
{
    var root = new Uri(baseUriString, UriKind.Absolute);
    var absolute = new Uri(root, relativePath);
    var segments = absolute.Segments;

    var thumbnailUri = new Uri(root, thumbsPath);
    var thumbSegments = thumbnailUri.Segments;

    var matchedRoot = Array.IndexOf(segments, thumbSegments[1]);

    var builder = new UriBuilder(root);

    for (var j = 1; j < segments.Length; j++)
    {
        if (j == matchedRoot)
        {
            for (var k = 1; k < thumbSegments.Length; k++)
            {
                builder.Path += thumbSegments[k];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            builder.Path += segments[j];
        }
    }

    return builder.Uri.ToString();
}
```

It seems convoluted. Any better way of doing this?

Comment: I'm guessing from your code that the shared segment may not always be the first segment? IE you could have "/myapp/images/...", with "/images/thumbnails/"?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your requirements correctly, you fundamentally want to:

1. Break the paths into segments
2. Find the overlapping first segment
3. Insert all the thumbs segments into that spot in the Uri.

Your code is already doing that, but I believe the following code makes those steps more clear:

```
    private static string GetThumbnail(string baseUriString, string relativePath, string thumbsPath)
    {
        // 1. Break the paths into segments
        // the trim here is important to prevent empty list items or "//" when we rebuild later.
        List<string> relativeSegments = relativePath.Trim('/').Split('/').ToList();
        List<string> thumbsSegments = thumbsPath.Trim('/').Split('/').ToList();

        // 2. Find the first segment of thumbs in the relative segments
        int sharedSegmentIndex = relativeSegments.IndexOf(thumbsSegments[0]);

        // 3. Insert all the thumbs segments into that spot in the Uri.
        // remove the overlapping segment (because we're adding it again below)
        relativeSegments.RemoveAt(sharedSegmentIndex);
        // insert the thumbs segment
        relativeSegments.InsertRange(sharedSegmentIndex, thumbsSegments);

        // build up the full path.
        var root = new Uri(baseUriString, UriKind.Absolute);
        var builder = new UriBuilder(root);
        builder.Path += string.Join("/", relativeSegments);

        return builder.Uri.ToString();
    }
```

Also, here is my quick and dirty test suite, so you can check I make the right desired outputs, and for anyone else wanting to tinker.

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        RunTest("http://www.blah.com/", "/images/2012-6/file.jpg", "/images/thumbnails/", "http://www.blah.com/images/thumbnails/2012-6/file.jpg");
        RunTest("http://www.blah.com/", "/images/folder/subfolder/test/again/filename.jpg", "/images/extra/thumbnails/", "http://www.blah.com/images/extra/thumbnails/folder/subfolder/test/again/filename.jpg");
        RunTest("http://www.blah.com/", "/myapp/images/folder/subfolder/test/again/filename.jpg", "/images/extra/thumbnails/", "http://www.blah.com/myapp/images/extra/thumbnails/folder/subfolder/test/again/filename.jpg");
    }

    public static void RunTest(string baseUriString, string relativePath, string thumbsPath, string expected)
    {
        var result = GetThumbnail(baseUriString, relativePath, thumbsPath);
        Debug.Assert(result == expected);
    }
```